# dynamically load javascript?

Tags: extjs, javascript

I use a lot of script in an application, some of them are not required to load the application, I want to load them just before their use if possible, knowing that my application is coded in ExtJS, and uses many ajax calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look at using [LABjs](http://labjs.com/) which is a script loader.

> Old and busted:

```
<script src="framework.js"></script>
<script src="plugin.framework.js"></script>
<script src="myplugin.framework.js"></script>
<script src="init.js"></script>
```

> New hotness:

```
<script>
   $LAB
   .script("framework.js").wait()
   .script("plugin.framework.js")
   .script("myplugin.framework.js").wait()
   .script("init.js").wait();
</script>
```

**Update**:
If you want to load jQuery you could do something like this from this [blog post](http://happyworm.com/blog/tag/labjs/).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="LAB.js">
if (typeof window.jQuery === "undefined") {
    $LAB.script("/local/jquery-1.4.min.js");
}
```

Comment: can you give me exemple how can i load Jquery and immediatly use it?

Comment: Found an example of loading jQuery for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can load an external file using javascript only when/where you need it:

```
function LoadJs(url){
  var js = document.createElement('script');

  js.type = "text/javascript";
  js.src = url;

  document.body.appendChild(js);

}

LoadJs("/path/to/your/file.js");
```

Comment: I agree with the direction your answer is heading, but I'd change a few things: createElement('script'); js.src = url; then append that to document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].

Comment: good catch on the create element bit but unless you have another defining reason you should put js at the bottom of your page:  http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great post on the topic with a proposed solution you might want to check out: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/02/14/separating-javascript-download-and-execution/